# How to store container modification on host

Tags: python, docker

I want to store the modification made in the container under /home/data/dir1/ so i added the volume in my dockerfile like below.

```
FROM python:3.9.0
ARG WORK_DIR=/opt/dir1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install cron -y && apt-get install -y default-jre
# Install python libraries
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
WORKDIR $WORK_DIR
EXPOSE 8888
# copy code on container under your workdir "/opt/dir1"
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c"]
CMD ["jupyter-notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root"]    
VOLUME /home/data/dir1/

then in my terminal i did

 #build
 docker build -t my-python-app .
 #run
 docker run -it -p 8888:8888 my-python-app
 #in container i did
 jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root
```

I think that my VOLUME doesn't work because when i did modifications in file of container nothing happens in the host /home/data/dir1/.

Does anyone knows why and how to solve it?

Comment: The most visible effect of a Dockerfile `VOLUME` directive is to tell Docker that later `RUN` commands can't modify the path you specify.  The path there is a container path, not a host path, and you don't need it for the various `docker run -v` mount options.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to persist data created while the container was running you probably should use some sort of `volumes` docker can save data to.

The **FIRST OPTION** is bind mounts - docker host-dependent directories you mount to a directory inside the container such that changes made in one side (let's say in the container) reflect in the other (or in this example the host mount). if you create a file in the host bind mount you should see it in the container, if you exec into it with `docker exec -it <container name or id> <command to run like bash \ sh, or with full path like /bin/sh>`

**SECOND OPTION** is "regular" docker volumes that you can manage through docker itself even while using the `docker <COMMAND>` CLI as specified [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Its much more versitile than bind mounts because you can mostly use any storage implementation you want, see usage and example [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/), I also added a small snippet for fast usage:

```
docker volume create my-volume
docker run -d -v my-volume:/home/data/dir1/ my-container-image:latest
```

Also if you ever need to move to another host you can save the volume and extract it in the other host like [so](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes)

Comment: ! thank you for your help, but when i red the documentation this command **docker run -d -v my-volume://home/data/dir1/ my-container-image:latest** mount data from host to container  ? It does both ? container--> host and host--> container ... Please excuse me i want just understand ^^

Comment: **Command**: docker run -v /doesnt/exist:/foo -w /foo -i -t ubuntu bash **Description in the doc**: The -v flag mounts the current working directory into the container. The -w lets the command being executed inside the current working directory, by changing into the directory to the value returned by pwd. So this combination executes the command using the container, but inside the current working directory.

Comment: using the second option you save the data created in the container in a docker volume that is (for the sake of the argument) a special format in which docker can save persistent data. think of it as a docker image, you cant see all the files like a regular bind mount unless you run it (like with an image) or bind it to a new container and `exec` into it with some shell command like `/bin/sh` or `bash` (like a docker volume)

Comment: Ahh its more clear now. So the same directory in the host can be used to be mounted in container et then used as volume to save container data in? TRUE.?

Comment: that can be done and it can be easier for some though its the less preferable option

Comment: Ok its clear thank you and then how to access to the folder volume to see if it works and the save was successful. ? thank you

Comment: as noted in a previouse comment you can run a dummy ubuntu or alpine container to see whats in the volume like so `docker run -v my-volume:/temp-checking-dir ubuntu ls -la`

Comment: @excellt please mark my answer if that helped you so we see the issue as closed :)